# Only allow navigation on specific domains and urls (blocking the rest) using privoxy on openwrt router

Tags: openwrt, privoxy

I've set up privoxy 3.0.24-1 on my router with OpenWrt (15.05).

The proxy is running and listening on port 8118.

I would like to filter url from my wireguard interface. I am you not using explicit proxy configuration (in the browser) but transparent redirect via iptables rules to redirect port 80 and 443 to 8118

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i wg0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8118

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i wg0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8118

I tried setting a example of blocking by only allowing 2 domains in a block rule:

```
{ -block}
.netflix.com
.disney.com
```

This rule can be found under the file user.action, which I include in my config in /etc/config/privoxy.
Both options 'toggle' and 'enforce_blocks' are set to 1. However, I do not see any filtered url from wireguard connections, the proxy doesn't block anything...

Any idea on that matter?

Is this something that can be achieved? And how?